# How do I fix this Syntax Error while building my React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, vite

Every time I try to run the npm run build command, it executes up until it exits with ELIFECYCLE error code errno 1. Honestly, this is someone else's code that I'm reviewing and trying to build and even the person who wrote it can't seem to figure this one out.

I know this says syntax error but I've taken a look at this node modules file and there's no syntax error that I can see.

I've spent my entire day on this now.... Any help will be really really appreciated.

Thank you all!

So, I installed all everything needed using "npm install"

I also installed wails, golang, npm, node, vite all of it on my device and still nothing.

The error I get when I execute npm run build is:

```
/home/user_name/path/path/code_folder/frontend/node_modules/vite/bin/vite.js:2
import { performance } from 'node:perf_hooks'
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! frontend@0.0.0 build: `vite build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the frontend@0.0.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/user_name/.npm/_logs/2023-03-29T12_36_29_654Z-debug.log


Output of the Log File is:

0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node', '/bin/npm', 'run', 'build' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.19.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
5 info lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~prebuild: frontend@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: frontend@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: PATH: /usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/home/user_name/path/path/project_folder/frontend/node_modules/.bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin
9 verbose lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: CWD: /home/user_name/path/path/project_folder/frontend
10 silly lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'vite build' ]
11 silly lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle frontend@0.0.0~build: Failed to exec build script
13 verbose stack Error: frontend@0.0.0 build: `vite build`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/share/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid frontend@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd /home/user_name/path/path/project_folder/frontend
16 verbose Linux 5.15.0-1035-azure
17 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/bin/npm" "run" "build"
18 verbose node v10.19.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error frontend@0.0.0 build: `vite build`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the frontend@0.0.0 build script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: try to delete the node modules folder and the running the install command as mentioned `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.

Comment: What version of Node are you running?

Comment: I'm using node version 10.19.0 and npm version 6.14.4 @Phil

Comment: I tried what you suggested, still got the same error again when I ran npm run build :( @Bharath

Comment: Node v10 became completely unsupported nearly 2 years ago. [Vite requires Node.js version 14.18+, 16+](https://vitejs.dev/guide/#scaffolding-your-first-vite-project)

Comment: @Phil you were right, it was an issue with the node version. I never even thought about that. Thanks a million you legend!